# Filter Matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have column vectors A and B:

```
A'= [1 2 0 0 1 4]
B'= [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

I would like to filter out the zeros in A and remove corresponding elements in B and have them as:

```
A' = [1 2 1 4] 
B' = [1 2 5 6]
```

I know there is a quick MATLAB command to do this, but cant figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest, easiest way is by using logical indexing:

```
A = [1 2 0 0 1 4].';
B = [1 2 3 4 5 6].';

nz = (A ~= 0); %# logical matrix for non-zeros in A

A = A(nz)      %# non-zeros of A
B = B(nz)      %# corresponding elements in B
```

Another way is the slightly slower

```
nz = find(A); %# vector of linear indices to non-zero elements

A = A(nz)     %# non-zeros of A
B = B(nz)     %# corresponding elements in B
```

Comment: Or as a short version of logical indexing: `A( A ~= 0 )`

Answer (score 2):

You can condense the logical indexing solutions further by removing the intermediate variable and changing the syntax slightly.

```
B=B(~~A)
A=A(~~A)
```

The only slight possible pitfall with removing an intermediate variable (i.e. `nz=~~A`) is that you have to remember to change `B` before changing `A`. This pitfall can be negated by converting the operation into a single command - the new values are not assigned to the variables until the right-hand-side of the expression has been evaluated.

```
[A,B] = deal(A(~~A),B(~~A))
```

Zen (if you're looking for the smallest amount of command characters), although I concur that efficiency might suffer (see comment).

Comment: Although a nice trick, it's 4 negations for getting rid of the temporary, plus the sensitivity to order of assignment...that's a steep price to pay for getting rid of a `clear tmp`

Comment: Good point. Agreed. The **best** solution will largely depend on the size of the arrays you are operating on for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it like this:

```
> A = [1 2 0 0 1 4]
A =

   1   2   0   0   1   4

> B = [1 2 3 4 5 6]
B =

   1   2   3   4   5   6

> V = find(A~=0)        % get the indices for which A <> 0 
V =

   1   2   5   6

> A = A(V)              % select elements from A
A =

   1   2   1   4

> B = B(V)              % select elements from B
B =

   1   2   5   6

>
```

Comment: You probably want to do B first, then A.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to remove the 0 element in A:

```
A0=A==0;
A(A0)=[]; 
B(A0)=[];
```

Howerver as @RodyOldenhuis said, `A(A0)=[]` is slower than `A=A(A0)`. So, when large loop is involved, or size of A is very large, `A(A0)=[]` should be avoided to use.

Comment: This is the way I'd go about it.  I'd even shrink it even more by saying `A(A==0)=[];` if you only had one variable.

Comment: Running 100,000 trials with either `A(A0)=[]` or `A=A(A~=0)` gives 0.89 seconds versus 0.38 seconds, respectively. Although it's more readable, the problem with this solution is that you should only use it when performance isn't critical...Used inside loops, it's usually disastrous.

Comment: I can confirm that they both work but as you just pointed `A=A(A~=0)` is faster